# Wordpress website not loading correctly. Syntax error and jQuery not defined?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I've been working on a WordPress-website for a client using a sub-domain and sub-folder and it is ready to launch. I have now moved all the files from the sub-folder to the root `public_html` using **FileZilla** but the page is not loading correctly. The content and everything seems fine but something is up with the jQuery. When I check the console it says:

```
" Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined at jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1:2

Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined at scripts.js?ver=5.1.4

Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery at bootstrap.min.js?ver=1.0.2:11

Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
at core.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11
at core.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11

Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
at script.min.js?ver=2.5.4:1 "
```

Something clearly went wrong when I moved the content of my sub-folder to the root. My WordPress Admin dashboard looks all messed up as well. 
There are no errors on the sub-domain website.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask You are required to post a [mcve] here, within your question, and not a link to your site.

Comment: Your jQuery version seems a bit old, can you try updating it to newer one. https://jquery.com/download/

Answer (score 1):

You error is that your js files has been broken by filezilla -

They have been downloaded in the wrong format, and now contains stuff like `��U c����U��U@��U`

Fix your filezilla (there is a setting, and i believe that the newest version has fixed this ), and download/upload again - these files are broken.

Download the JS files as binary insted of Ascii.

I've had this error before.

You can see it in your jquery file : http://demenskontakten.dk/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp

Comment: Yes exactly! Thank you! I will try this.